# How to compile openssl1.0 for arm based busybox system?

Tags: openssl, cross-compiling

I am trying to compile libssl.so for an arm based linux busybox system that is running an `arm926ej-s rev 5` cpu, I got the source code from the official [website](https://www.openssl.org/source/old/1.0.0/openssl-1.0.0s.tar.gz)

The compile steps are as follows:

1. `wget https://www.openssl.org/source/old/1.0.0/openssl-1.0.0s.tar.gz`
2. `tar xvf openssl-1.0.0s.tar.gz`
3. `cd openssl-1.0.0s`
4. `./config --prefix=/usr/local/openssl-arm --openssldir=/usr/local/openssl-arm shared no-ssl2 no-ssl3 no-comp no-hw no-engine --cross-compile-prefix=arm-linux-gnueabi-`
5. `make`

after step number 5 I get multiple `bad instruction` errors, full output is on [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/raw/KMwPJAEF)

I did change the Makefile a bit  on lines `64`, `154` where i changed `-m64` to `-marm`

Am I missing something and how does one compile a shared library for arm linux